# Perform glob expansion explicitly when `-f` flag is enabled

Tags: shell-script

I've seen in a guides (e.g. this one https://sipb.mit.edu/doc/safe-shell/) recommending using `set -f` to disable glob expansion (in sh and bash). Is there a way to explicitly perform glob expansion when this option is enabled other than using another shell `sh -c 'echo *'` or temporarily disabling the option`set +f; echo *; set -f`?

Comment: `zsh` does not honor `set -f`, you have to `set` the `zsh` option `noglob` explicitly to turn off globbing..

Comment: I disagree strongly with that guide.  The answer is, learn to use shell properly.  Start by checking out the top-voted questions/answers for [shell-script](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shell-script?sort=votes&pageSize=15), [quoting](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quoting?sort=votes&pageSize=15), [wildcards](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wildcards?sort=votes&pageSize=15), etc.

Comment: I have found a few C library functions for performing shell-like glob expansion like `glob` and `glob-free` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html and `wordexp` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wordexp.3.html ... but so far no command line utilities wrapping these things.